# Go SQL Exec not changing value in database

Tags: mysql, go, percona

I wrote a program that creates and loads data into a database using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. The LOAD DATA part works fine, but after that I run UPDATE query. The update query returns nil as an error, and return that 1 row was affected (as expected). But when I check in the database, the value never changed. When I run UPDATE query manually in MySQL console, it works fine. Also, there are no locked or "hanging" queries. Here is the code:

```
// Load data
var loadDataCommand = fmt.Sprintf("set autocommit = 0; set foreign_key_checks = 0; set sql_log_bin = 0; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE %s COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES; commit; set autocommit = 1; set foreign_key_checks = 1; set sql_log_bin = 1;", filepath.Join(directoryName, tableName + ".txt"), tableName))
_, err := db.Exec(loadDataCommand)
if err != nil { panic(err) }


// Update table
_, err = db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE states.cities SET states.cities.online = %d WHERE states.cities.city_id = '%s'", status, cityId))
```

The only way I managed to "fix" this is to close and reopen the database connection. This is how I open the connection.

```
newDbConnection, err := sql.Open(DatabaseDriver, DatabaseUser+":"+DatabasePassword+"@tcp("+DatabaseAddress+":3306)/"+DatabaseName+"?multiStatements=true")

if err == nil {
    newDbConnection.SetMaxOpenConns(MaxNumberOfDatabaseConnections)
    newDbConnection.SetMaxIdleConns(MaxNumberOfDatabaseConnections)
    newDbConnection.SetConnMaxLifetime(MaxAgeOfDatabaseConnection)

    db = newDbConnection
}
```

Also if I run the UPDATE query before `LOAD DATA`, it works fine. The weirdest part is that the UPDATE query returns correct value (1 row affected) and nil as an error...

Comment: In the first `Exec` you set `autocommit=0`, so maybe you have to commit it after the `UPDATE` statement? Or set autocommit back to its original value after the first statement.

Comment: I set autocommit to original value (autocommit=1) after `LOAD DATA`

Comment: Yes you do. I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: The fact that closing and reopening your connection fixes it, plus the fact that you are starting with `set autocommit = 0` (regardless of resetting it to 1) makes me very suspicious.

Comment: sql.Open does not return a connection. Go sql library maintains a connection pool behind the scenes. Each call to db.Exec or db.Query etc can run on different connections. Use a transaction to ensure calls are on the same database connection. See [Modifying Data and Using Transactions](http://go-database-sql.org/modifying.html).

Comment: @Mark Using `Begin()` and `Commit()` fixed the issue, but I can't say I understand why. Especially since other `.Exec()` commands work fine without Begin and Commit called.